# Android Text view not allow & nSymbol for dynamic text view

Tags: android-ndk

I am retrieving text from web server in that text & symbol is there when i try to display that data & after text is not displaying like (Handy & Harmon) "Android" text is displaying "& Java" text is not displaying so what should i do to display all data in my text view. This text i am retriving from php server

This below Html Tags from php server i am using saxparser to retrive this data from webserver

```
-<Data><Price_type>Silver</Price_type>
<Prices>$39.80</Prices>
<Price_location>Handy & Harmon </Price_location></Data>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this textview.setText(new String(strvar.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));

Answer (score 0):

If you have acces to the web server change tags containing special characters using CDATA. Example:

```
<Data><Price_type>Silver</Price_type>
<Prices>$39.80</Prices>
<Price_location><![CDATA[Handy & Harmon]]></Price_location></Data>
```